# Push error with lots of files. fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly. error RPC failed; curl 55 send failure: Connection was aborted

Tags: github

I am having issues pushing my latest commits for an UE4 project. The commit contains a huge number of changed or added files.

**Github Error when pushing:**

> fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly.
>   error RPC failed; curl 55 send failure: Connection was aborted.
>   Everything up-to-date

I would like some advice how I should go forward with this issue. Will it work to upload the entire update as a new repository or branch or could it be solved in a better way? There is weeks of work done since the last commit so it is important that no information gets lost.

Image of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwgCp.png

Tried to increase post buffer size for uploading, with git config command: `http.postBuffer 524288000`
the same issue persisted even after this.

I would like the commit to be pushed or uploaded in any way possible. This is my first post on Stack overflow and I would be very grateful for any help or advice I may get regarding this issue.